# Go interface is (type, nil) or (type , value)

Tags: interface, go

Hi I want ask a question about interface is nil

```
//i think err should be a interface (*MyError, nil)
var err error = (*MyError)(nil)
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(err)) 
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(err))`
```

the result told me interface value is not nil
result :

```
*main.MyError
<*main.MyError Value>
```

it's equivalent to interface `(*main.MyError, <*main.MyError Value>)`
why the interface value is not nil?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two things are completely different:

- The `nil` interface value. It does not hold an underlying type or value.
- A non-`nil` interface value, which holds an underlying type and value, and that underlying value is `nil` in that underlying type (if it's one of the types that have a value called `nil` -- pointer, slice, map, channel, or function). Note that different types' `nil`s are different and unrelated (pointer-`nil` and map-`nil` are unrelated); and some types don't have a value called `nil`.

You have a `nil` pointer (`*MyError` type), and you assign that to an interface variable (first of interface type `error`, then converted to interface type `interface{}` which is the parameter type of `reflect.TypeOf()` and `reflect.ValueOf()`). Therefore, those functions receive a non-`nil` interface value containing an underlying type `*MyError` and underlying value `nil`.

`reflect.TypeOf(err)` gets the underlying type, which is `*MyError`. And `reflect.ValueOf(err)` constructs a `reflect.Value` object representing the underlying type and value. This is what you see.

The [stringification of a `reflect.Value`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.String) produces the string `<T value>`, where `T` is the type, but it doesn't try to stringily the value (`nil` pointer in this case). If you wanted to print the underlying value, perhaps you should have just done `fmt.Println(err)` instead.

Comment: i was understand that the reflect.ValueOf(err)'s result is <*main.MyError Value>.  why the Error() method could be called by err (interface<*MyError, nil>)?

Comment: @BrainWu: The variable `err` is of type `error`, an interface which includes the method `Error()`. So you can call `Error()` on it, no matter what the underlying type is. The fact that `*MyError` conforms to the interface `error` means that there is an `Error` method defined on type `*MyError` (or on type `MyError`). If there is an `Error` method defined on type `*MyError`, then it will be called when you call `.Error()` on a value of underlying type `*MyError`, no matter if the underlying value is `nil` or not.

Answer (score 0):

http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf

> ValueOf returns a new Value initialized to the concrete value stored
>   in the interface i. **ValueOf(nil) returns the zero Value.**